EAs using MQL5 convert pine script
I am looking to write an RSI indicator with input as RSI based array of pine script language like below:
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

where the function rma is defined as:
pine_rma(src, length) =>
    alpha = 1/length
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? ta.sma(src, length) : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])

This RSI calculation is not the same as the theories I learned, is there any way to convert it to mql5 correctly? here is the code I am writing:
double SimpleMA(double &data[], int period, int shift = 0)
{

    if (ArraySize(data) < shift + period) {
        Print("Not enough data in data[]");
        return(-1);
    }

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = shift; i < shift + period; i++)
    {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return sum / period;
}
double RMA(double &data[], int period, int shift = 0)
{
    double alpha = 1.0 / (double)period;
    double sum = SimpleMA(data, period, shift); // giả sử bạn đã viết hàm SimpleMA

    for(int i = shift + period; i < ArraySize(data); i++)
    {
        sum = alpha * data[i] + (1 - alpha) * sum;
    }

    return sum;
}
double CustomRSI(double &haClose[], int period, int shift = 0)
{
    if (ArraySize(haClose) < shift + period) {
        Print("Not enough data in haClose[]");
        return(-1);
    }

    double gain[], loss[];
    ArrayResize(gain, period);
    ArrayResize(loss, period);

    for (int i = shift; i < shift + period; i++)
    {
        double change = haClose[i] - haClose[i+1];
        if (change > 0) {
            gain[i-shift] = change;
            loss[i-shift] = 0;
        } else {
            gain[i-shift] = 0;
            loss[i-shift] = -change;
        }
    }

    double avgGain = RMA(gain, period);
    double avgLoss = RMA(loss, period);


    double rs = (avgGain + avgLoss) == 0 ? 0 : avgGain / avgLoss;
    double rsi = 100 - (100 / (1 + rs));

    return rsi;
}

please give me advice. thanks very much!
If you have any ideas please help me.Thanks very much.
